# Search algorithm - Java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am finding it a little bit difficult to get a search algorithm to work properly in Java.  Basically, the program has an array initialized.  The user is supposed to enter a number via the keyboard, and Java will them print out the all the indexes where this number is found.  My main problem lies in the fact that I want create a method which currently looks as follows:

```
    public static int[] linsearch(int[] numbers, int key) {
        int[] indexvalues = null;
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] == key) {
                indexvalues[n] = i;
                n++;}
        }

        return indexvalues;
    }
```

The idea behind this is that given an array, and a number (in this case identified by "key"), the program will create a new array in which the indexes of where the number "key" is found in the original array will be saved.  Currently I get this error message:  java.lang.NullPointerException.  I have tried different approaches to initializing this array, but none have been succesful so far.  Thus, any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: This is a story, not a question. Debug to the point where you have the minimum failing example.

Comment: OK.  I have shortened my question.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm sorry, I'm still very, very new to programming (started only 2 months ago), so forgive me if my questions are sometimes not as elegant as all the others on this site.

Answer (score 3):

The main difficulty stems from the fact that you don't know the size of the output array ahead of time. On the other hand, growing a Java array as needed is doable, but unpleasant.

There are several ways to fix this.

If I were you, I'd use a collection to store the indices:

```
public static Collection<Integer> linsearch(int[] numbers, int key) {
    ArrayList<Integer> indexvalues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == key) {
            indexvalues.add(i);
        }
    }
    return indexvalues;
}
```

You'll need to modify the calling code accordingly. I leave this as an exercise for the reader.